# Couldn't match type a with a1, but types look identical

Tags: haskell

I'm learning Haskell and the compiler is giving me an error I don't quite understand. It says the expected and actual types do not match, but to me they look identical. Can anyone help me understand what this error is trying to say?

```
/app/app/Main.hs:75:11: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘a’ with ‘a1’
      ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          app :: forall a.
                 (ReaderT (W.Options -> String -> IO (Response BL.ByteString)) IO a
                  -> IO a)
                 -> IO Middleware
        at /app/app/Main.hs:68:1-99
      ‘a1’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        a type expected by the context:
          forall a1.
          ReaderT (W.Options -> String -> IO (Response BL.ByteString)) IO a1
          -> IO a1
        at /app/app/Main.hs:75:3-12
      Expected type: ReaderT
                       (W.Options -> String -> IO (Response BL.ByteString)) IO a1
                     -> IO a1
        Actual type: ReaderT
                       (W.Options -> String -> IO (Response BL.ByteString)) IO a
                     -> IO a
    • In the first argument of ‘spockT’, namely ‘(r)’
      In the expression: spockT (r)
      In a stmt of a 'do' block: spockT (r) $ routes apiKey template
    • Relevant bindings include
        r :: ReaderT
               (W.Options -> String -> IO (Response BL.ByteString)) IO a
             -> IO a
          (bound at /app/app/Main.hs:69:5)
        app :: (ReaderT
                  (W.Options -> String -> IO (Response BL.ByteString)) IO a
                -> IO a)
               -> IO Middleware
          (bound at /app/app/Main.hs:69:1)
   |
75 |   spockT (r) $ routes apiKey template
   |           ^
```

What's even more confusing to me is that all I'm doing is moving a function from being called directly to be a parameter.

The code that fails is below (simplified), but if I inline `runner` i.e. remove it as a parameter to `app`, all works fine.

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  runSpock 8080 $ app runner

runner :: ReaderT (W.Options -> String -> IO (Response BL.ByteString)) m a -> m a
runner r = runReaderT r W.getWith

app :: (ReaderT (W.Options -> String -> IO (Response BL.ByteString)) IO a -> IO a) -> IO Middleware
app runner = do
  spockT (runner) $ routes

routes :: MonadIO m => SpockCtxT ctx (ReaderT (W.Options -> String -> IO (Response BL.ByteString)) m) ()
routes = do
  get "healthz" $ text "ok"
```

Comment: Could you post the error from the code you posted?

Comment: What's `spockT`?

Comment: @melpomene Likely it's [this one](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/Spock-core-0.13.0.0/docs/Web-Spock-Core.html#v:spockT) from *Spock-core*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the library you're using, but the argument to `spockT` is required to be polymorphic. You're saying that the person who *calls* `app` gets to determine what `a` is. But `spockT` wants to make that determination itself (possibly in multiple ways). Specifically,

```
spockT :: MonadIO m => (forall a. m a -> IO a) -> SpockT m () -> IO Middleware
```

Try adding `{-# language RankNTypes #-}` to the top of your file and changing the signature of `app` to

```
app
  :: (forall a. ReaderT (W.Options -> String -> IO (Response BL.ByteString)) IO a -> IO a)
  -> IO Middleware
```

A bit more explanation:

The type of `spockT` looks like

```
spockT :: MonadIO m => (forall a. m a -> IO a) -> ...
```

What's that all about? The `MonadIO` class looks like this

```
class Monad m => MonadIO m where
  liftIO :: IO a -> m a
```

That means if you have `MonadIO m`, then you have a function `forall a. IO a -> m a`. The function argument to `spockT` looks a lot like that, but it goes the other way. If `m` wraps up an `IO` action with some sort of "context", then the function has to strip off that context, perhaps adding additional information.

Comment: Thank you so much for the fix and explanation, this worked perfectly!